# ms access passing a form's text box values to reports using Global Variables

Tags: ms-access, vba, global-variables

I have a form named frm_Reports from which I’m opening different types of reports with different combo boxes.  At the end of the report I have a textbox in which I’m summing up the records in the report and showing a statement like this

> 325 patients entered from above grouped departments for lab tests from Friday, 1st March 2019 to Thursday,  21st March 2019

I have the following expression to display this statement

```
=Sum([CountOfPatientID]) & "  patients entered from above grouped departments for lab tests from  " & Format([GetSDV],"dddd"",  ""dd mmmm yyyy") & "  to  " & Format([GetEDV],"dddd  dd mmmm yyyy")
```

GetSDV and GetEDV are public functions.

I’m trying to bring the dates in the statement from the text boxes on the form from which I opened the reports.

I know I have to use Global variables and wrapper functions around the variables to enter date values in the statement. But when I try to open the report the date values do not get picked up and it asks me to enter the parameter values for the functions.

Here is the code I’m trying to do this with

```
Option Compare Database

Global SDV As Date
Global EDV As Date

Public Function GetSDV()
    GetSDV = SDV
End Function

Public Function GetEDV()
    GetEDV = EDV
End Function

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    GetSDV
    GetEDV
End Sub

Public Sub btn_PatientCount_Click()
    CheckForSDNulls
    CheckForEDNulls
    SDV = Me.txt_StartDate
    EDV = Me.txt_EndDate
    If IsNull(Me.cbo_PatientCount) Then
    MsgBox "Please select a report from the dropdown menu.", vbInformation, "No Report Selected"
    Exit Sub
    Else: DoCmd.OpenReport cbo_PatientCount.Column(1), acViewPreview, "", , acWindowNormal
    End If
End Sub
```

I have even tried many tweaks in the code but nothing has still worked out for.

Comment: Have you step debugged? Instead of global variables and functions, report could just reference the form controls directly. Another approach is to pass the date values with OpenArgs and code within report extracts the values.

Comment: Thank you for this but I'm not very good with openarg

Comment: And directly referencing from the report to form didn't work for me because just after i opened the reported i close the form and when i go to the last page of the report where this text box actually come to play at footer of the report it gave nulls 
Still thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should read the functions:

```
=Sum([CountOfPatientID]) & " patients entered from above grouped departments for lab tests from  " & Format(GetSDV(),"dddd"",  ""dd mmmm yyyy") & "  to  " & Format(GetEDV(),"dddd  dd mmmm yyyy")
```

And this could be optimised:

```
Public Function GetSDV() As Date
    GetSDV = SDV
End Function

Public Function GetEDV() As Date
    GetEDV = EDV
End Function
```

Doesn't do anything.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    GetSDV
    GetEDV
End Sub
```

and do apply a date format to the *Format* property of the textboxes - or convert to date:

```
SDV = CDate(Me!txt_StartDate.Value)
EDV = CDate(Me!txt_EndDate.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude. just worked like a charm
but why instead of giving date values it's giving time 
and it's picking dates like 1898

Comment: Sounds like the textboxes are not read as date. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Yep, converting was good thing i guess but i guess it problem somewhere in when i moved this code 

SDV = CDate(Me!txt_StartDate.Value)
EDV = CDate(Me!txt_EndDate.Value)

to date field's after update event 
it didn't work there properly i don't why 
but back to the open report button on click even it fires fine 

thanks again 
it's 2pm here, i'm working on tomorrow's deadline and you are helping so quick and for so long 
really owe you 

#Tell me if you visit my city someday 
Dinner would be from me

Comment: Great! I've made a note of that, though I doubt I'll ever travel that far.

Comment: Where are you from